# WCF Service Hosted in Windows Service won't run properly

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp, windows-services

I actually have two different problems depending on the way that I try to run the service that look related but show themselves in different ways. Note that the code that I am running is an EXACT duplicate of the code used in [Microsofts guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx) with the exception of different namespaces and slightly different class names.

When I tried to run the service using this method the windows service started successfully but when it did the WCF Service Host box would pop up and it gave an error message that said there is already a listener on IP endpoint localhost:. Here is my config file when I ran this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CfmaWcfEphemerisLibrary.ServiceBehavior"
               name="CfmaWcfEphemerisLibrary.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="CfmaWcfEphemerisLibrary.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8529/Service1" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CfmaWcfEphemerisLibrary.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

After fighting for a while I found a suggestion that said enabling port sharing on the tcp connection might help. I tried that but when I try to start the service it fails and in the Windows Events Logs under "Application" i get an error that says:

> Service cannot be started. System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:8529.  Make sure that you are not trying to use this endpoint multiple times in your application and that there are no other applications listening on this endpoint. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnectionListener.Listen()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ExclusiveTcpTransportManager.OnOpen()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels....

I can't figure out why I'm getting a port in use exception on a port that has sharing enabled. Here is my App.config file when I try to run the service with port sharing enabled.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CfmaWcfEphemerisLibrary.ServiceBehavior"
               name="CfmaWcfEphemerisLibrary.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
          contract="CfmaWcfEphemerisLibrary.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8529/Service1" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CfmaWcfEphemerisLibrary.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding portSharingEnabled="true" name="tcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security>
            <transport>
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
            </transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Go to a command prompt. Run netstat -a . Make sure there is nothing already using port 8529. Also it might be helpful if you posted the code on how you are creating and staring your WCF service host inside your windwos service.

Comment: I did the netstat but nothing is listed. I will post my code when i get back to my dev box

Comment: If there is nothing already using port 8529, then that would be evidence pointing towards your Windows services attempting to start multiple copies of the WCF service host.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the problem with using the same port for metadata exchange:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702636.aspx
see "Sharing a port between a service endpoint and a mex endpoint using the NetTcpBinding" section.

In two words, this fixes the problem:
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8530/mex" ...>